# Touchpad Stopped working

Tags: touchpad

Touchpad has stopped working in DEll Inspiron 5521 (ubuntu 14.04).Touchpad is not detected by xinput list .But mouse is working in Ubuntu.Also touchpad is working in windows.

Comment: What happens if you press Fn+F3? (fn is rsecond fron the left, bottom row next to the ctrl key, f3 has a little picture of a touchpad on it on the Dell 5521)